# Merge DataFrame float column with DataFrame pandas Interval column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, intervals

I have 2 DataFrames that I want to merge.

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
'names':['klas','erik','stefan'],
'age':[6,17.5,28] 
})

df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
{'salary':[10,15,45,600],
 'names':['klas','erik','stefan','stefan'],
 'age_range':pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0,10),(10,20),(20,30),(0,10)])    
})
```

df1:

```
    names   age
0   klas    6
1   erik    17.5
2   stefan  28
```

df2:

```
  salary names  age_range
0   10   klas   (0, 10]
1   15   erik   (10, 20]
2   45   stefan (20, 30]
3   600  stefan (0, 10]
```

If I merge on the names column the age in the last row is not in the interval
in the interval column ((0, 10]):

```
m1=df1.merge(df2,on='names',how='left')
print(m1)

    names  age  salary   age_range
0   klas    6     10      (0, 10]
1   erik    17.5  15      (10, 20]
2   stefan  28    45      (20, 30]
3   stefan  28    600     (0, 10]
```

What I really want to do is merge on the keys/columns age and age_range.
The problem is that age is a column with floats and age range is a column
with pandas Intervals. It is unfortunately not possible to do a merge like this:

```
df1.merge(df2,left_on=['age','names'],right_on=['age_range','names'],how='left')
```

This just results in a salary column with nans.
To currently get the result I want i have to do the merge on names and then
do something like:

```
def check_if_age_between(age,age_range):
    return age in age_range

f1=lambda row: check_if_age_between(row['age'],row['age_range'])

m1=m1[m1.apply(f1,axis=1)]

print(m1)


    names  age  salary  age_range
0    klas    6      10   (0, 10]
1    erik   17.5    15   (10, 20]
2  stefan   28      45   (20, 30]
```

Is there a way to do a merge with 2 df:s using the keys of a float
column in the first df and a pandas interval column in the second df?

**(Edit: Replaced 17 with 17.5 in age values in df1 to make it into a float and not int column)**

Comment: `conditional_join` should help here

Comment: Ok is that a pandas function? If not could you please provide package name?

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamicaly define your bins, if your age ranges in df2 don't overlap nor have gaps like this:

```
df1["age_range"] = pd.cut(
    df1["age"],
    bins=[df2["age_range"].iloc[0].left]
    + sorted([e.right for e in df2["age_range"].iloc[1:]]),
)
```

You can apply a age range to the first dataframe, using `pd.cut` and then merge like this:

```
df1['age_range'] = pd.cut(df1['age'], bins=[0,10,20,30,40])
df_out = df1.merge(df2, on = ['names', 'age_range'])

df_out
```

Output:

```
    names  age age_range  salary
0    klas    6   (0, 10]      10
1    erik   17  (10, 20]      15
2  stefan   28  (20, 30]      45
```

Comment: I can place the floats in discrete bins/intervals like this and then do the merge. Problem is that I dont want to have to manually update a list with discrete bins. What if some interval ranges change and become wider/tighter etc.

Comment: @Niltzable See update.

Answer (score 2):

[conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) covers your use case - you create temporary columns of start and end from your interval array:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
(df1
.conditional_join(
    df2.assign(start=df2.age_range.array.left, 
               end=df2.age_range.array.right), 
    # column from the left, column from the right, operator
    ('names', 'names', '=='), 
    ('age', 'start', '>='), 
    ('age', 'end', '<='), 
    # columns to return from the right dataframe
    right_columns=['salary','age_range'], 
    # more performance may be possible in numba
    # if you have many duplicated values in the equality join
    use_numba=False,
    # you may force the inequality join to execute first
    # if you know that there are less rows to return
    # compared to the inequality join
    force=False,
    how = 'inner')
) 
    names  age  salary age_range
0    klas    6      10   (0, 10]
1    erik   17      15  (10, 20]
2  stefan   28      45  (20, 30]
```

Another option, if you wish to avoid any other third party, is to use the in operator, where you check per row, it is an o(n) operation so I dont expect that much performance difference:

```py
out = df1.merge(df2, on='names')
filtered = [a in b for a, b in zip(out.age, out.age_range)]
out.loc[filtered]
    names  age  salary age_range
0    klas    6      10   (0, 10]
1    erik   17      15  (10, 20]
2  stefan   28      45  (20, 30]
```

A fully vectorized approach would be to dip into the array and grab the left and right ends:

```py
out = df1.merge(df2, on='names')
filtered = out.age.between(out.age_range.array.left, 
                           out.age_range.array.right)
out.loc[filtered]
    names  age  salary age_range
0    klas    6      10   (0, 10]
1    erik   17      15  (10, 20]
2  stefan   28      45  (20, 30]
```

Comment: Very useful stuff, thanks